# How can I remove the singleton dimensions of an array?

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have an array `A`, for which `Dimensions[A]` is `{9, 9, 1, 1, 3, 4}`, how can I convert `A`' into an array with dimensions `{9, 9, 3, 4}`?

I think there is a built-in function for this, but I can't remember its name.

Comment: What is meant by conversion of dimension ? Repositioning element or just removing 1 from list ?

Comment: It is just the same array logically; however, mathematica's Dimensions[] function will identify them as different arrays with different dimensions.

Comment: E.g, If I have {{a,b},{c,d}}, it is {2,2} in sizes; sometimes it can also be {2,2,1,1,1}; How to make sure mathematica's Dimensions only obtain the simplest result {2,2}?

Comment: Flatten does work, but it is complicate this way; there should be a simpler way with only one simple Function but I forget the name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could get the array's dimensions, remove the 1's and use that in `ArrayReshape`:

```
array = Array[f, {9, 9, 1, 1, 3, 4}];
new = ArrayReshape[array, Dimensions[array] ~DeleteCases~ 1];
Dimensions[new]
(*  {9, 9, 3, 4} *)
```

If efficiency is not important you could use a replacement rule:

```
new = array //. {x_} :> x
Dimensions[new]
(*  {9, 9, 3, 4} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems I was confused by Matlab's "squeeze" which removes singleton dimensions while Mathematica doesnot have such a function.

Comment: `ArrayReshape` is a thing now? Sweet!

Answer (score 3):

```
array = Array[f, {9, 9, 1, 1, 3, 4}];
Dimensions[array]
```

> {9,9,1,1,3,4}

```
newArray=Flatten[array , {{1}, {2}, {5}, {6, 3, 4}}];  
 Dimensions[newArray]
```

> {9,9,3,4}

Comment: Thank you. The desired solution should be that, the user don't have to use the original array's dimension information. If these are available, I would prefer to use ArrayReshape[]

Answer (score 3):

Another way to use `Flatten` is to collect the trivial (single-element) levels with the first nontrivial level:

```
flattenTrivialLevels[array_] := 
 Flatten[array, 
   Flatten[{Position[#, _?(# > 1 &), 1, 1], Position[#, 1]} &@ Dimensions[array]]]
```

OP's test case (compared with Simon Woods' elementary replacement method):

```
array = RandomInteger[10, {9, 9, 1, 1, 3, 4}];
flat = flattenTrivialLevels[array];
new = array //. {x_} :> x;
Dimensions[flat]
flat === new

(* {9, 9, 3, 4} *)
(* True *)
```

The `Flatten` command being used is `Flatten[array, {1, 3, 4}]`.

An arbitrary variation:

```
array = RandomInteger[10, {1, 9, 1, 9, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4}];
flat = flattenTrivialLevels[array];
new = array //. {x_} :> x;
Dimensions[flat]
flat === new

(* {9, 9, 3, 4} *)
(* True *)
```